# The minimum privilege needed to list Shared Drives

Tags: google-drive-api

When using the Google Drive API with domain delegation, we want to figure out the minimum privileges the impersonated GSuite account needs to have to be able to list all Shared Drives of the organization. From our testing, unless the account has the "Drive and Docs > Settings" administrator privilege, the Drives.list API fails with error noListTeamDrivesAdministratorPrivilege

Is there a read-only privilege we can grant the GSuite account in order to be able to list all shared drives while impersonating as that account using domain delegation?

Answer (score 1):

### You can see the access level overview [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7337554?hl=en):

[image]

In other words, for a user to be able to list shared drives, he needs the `Viewer` privilege for all Drives he is meant to list.